# Некорректное отображение логина пользователя в браузере Firefox

Tags: php, html

Есть такая функция на php:

```
<?php 
$g = '<div class="register"><ul><li class="it"><a href="/register" class="button">Регистрация</a></li></ul></div>';
$glogin = '<div class="register"><ul><li class="it"><a href="/profile" class="button">'.$_SESSION['USER_LOGIN'].'</a></li></ul></div>';

function G() {
global $g, $glogin;
    if ($_SESSION['USER_LOGIN_IN'] != 1) {
        $Test = $g;
    } else {
        $Test = $glogin;
    }
    echo ''.$Test.'';                                  
}
?>
```

Но проблема заключается в том, что Firefox не отображает переменную `$_SESSION['USER_LOGIN']` (логин пользователя). В остальных браузерах все работает нормально.

Comment: html код страницы покажите в районе отображения логина из Firefox.

Comment: да по любому не залогинены ведь в фф

Comment: Здесь код не влезет, залил сюда:
https://hello-site.ru/share/Kod-Stack/

Comment: А в шаблонах у вас случайно этот код не может быть прописан? Ни как php, а как текст?

Comment: Прописан таким образом: <?php G()?>
А если заменить $_SESSION['USER_LOGIN'] на $_SESSION['USER_EMAIL'] то все работает нормально и показывает почту пользователя, но конечно хотелось бы заменить ее на логин.

Comment: @lovo, логин кроме букв/цифр еще что содержит? А то по правилам нужно было через http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php его прогнать для вывода в браузер!

Comment: Использую такую функцию:
function FormChars($p1, $p2 = 0) {
global $CONNECT;
if ($p2) {
        return mysqli_real_escape_string($CONNECT, $p1);
    } else {
        return nl2br(htmlspecialchars(trim($p1), ENT_QUOTES), false);
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Решено. Было пару ошибок в html коде, по невнимательности забыл закрыть теги `</header>` и `</a>` Всем спасибо за помощь!